# Using fsolve to solve a set of equations where one is a sigma function that changes every iteration

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am working on a finance project to solve a set of equations that enables me to go from par spread to flat spread in terms of CDS.

I have a set of data for the upfront (`U`) and years (`i`), where to set the data sample, I name upfront with `x` and years in `y`

```
x = [-0.007,-0.01,-0.009,-0.004,0.005,0.011,0.018,0.027,0.037,0.048]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Here are the 3 equations that I am trying to solve together:

```
U = A(s(i)-c)
L(i) = 1 - (1 - (s(i) / (1 - R)) ** i) / (1 - (1 / (s(i-1) - R)) ** (i - 1))
A = sum([((1 - L(i)) / (1 + r)) ** j for j in range(1, i+1)])
```

Detailed explanation:

- The goal is to solve and list the results for all 10 values of variable `s`
- 1st equation is used to calculate the upfront amount, where `s` is unknown
- 2nd equation is used to calculate the hazard rate `L`, where `R` is recovery rate, `s(i)` is the current `s` term and `s(i-1)` is the previous `s` term.
  Visual representation of equation 2:
  [image: Visual representation of equation 2]
- 3rd equation is used to calculate the annual risky annuity, the purpose of this equation is to calculate and sum the risk annuities. For example, if `i=1`, then there should be one term in the equation. If `i=2`, then there should be 2 terms in the equation where they are summed. This repeats until the 10th iteration where there are 10 values and they are summed.
  Visual representation of equation 3:
  [image: Visual representation of equation 3]

To attempt to solve the problem, I wrote the following code (which doesn't run yet):

```
x = [-0.007,-0.01,-0.009,-0.004,0.005,0.011,0.018,0.027,0.037,0.048]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
c = 0.01
r = 0.01
R = 0.4

def eqs(s, U, t, c=0.01, r=0.01, R=0.4):

   L = 1 - (1 - (s / (1 - R)) ** t) / (1 - (1 / (1 - R)) ** (t - 1))
   A = sum([((1 - L) / (1 + r)) ** j for j in range(1, i+1)])
   s = (U/A) + c
   return L, A, s

for U, t in zip(x, y):
   s = fsolve(eq1, 0.01, (U, t,))
   print(s, U, t)
```

Main obstacles:

- I haven't found a way where I can make Equation 3 work.
- I also haven't been able to pass through 2 sets of values into the for loop that then calls the function
- I wasn't able to loop the previous spread value, `s(i-1)`, back into the iteration to compute the next value
- I was able to solve it manually on python by changing the third equation every iteration and inputting the previous results

I am hoping I can find some solution to my problem, thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It looks like you want to compute the values of your formulas for each of your data, not to solve equations, fsolve is made for finding solutions of f(x)=0 problems and I dont think it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, would you know which solver I should use instead?

Comment: Could you give the first equation and explain how you calculate S0, S1 and if there is a recurring relationship for the following Sn.

Comment: In terms of the equations, the second equation is substituted into lambdas in the third equation, the Risk Annuity in the this equation is then substituted into 'A' in the first equation. There is no geometric/arthemetric sequence, not that I am aware of. S0 is actually not required because when i =1, the bottom of the fraction in the second equation goes to 1 so the only unknown left is s1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a bit but I think I got it. Your main problem is that you can't code formulas which describe a complex problem, then call a 'magic' fsolve function and hoping that python will solve it for you, without even defining what is the unknown.

It doesn't work that way. You have to make your problem simple enough so that it can be solved with existing functions from some libraries. Python has no form of intelligence nor divination.

As I said in my comments, the fsolve() from scipy.optimise can only solve problems of the form f(x)=0. 
If you want to use it, you have to transform your complex problem in a simple f(x)=0. problem.

Starting from your 3rd equation `s = (U/A) + c` we can deduce that `s - (U/A) - c = 0`
Given that A is a function of L and L is a function of s, if you define a function `f(s)= s - (U/A) - c` then `s` is the  solution of `f(s)=0`.

It is what I did in the following code :

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def Lambda(s,sold,R,t):
    num = (1 - s    / (1 - R)) ** t
    den = (1 - sold / (1 - R)) ** (t - 1)
    return 1-num/den

def Annuity(L,r,Aold,j):
    return Aold + ((1 - L) / (1 + r)) ** j

def f(s,U, sold,R,t,r,Aold,j):
    L=Lambda(s,sold,R,t)
    A=Annuity(L,r,Aold,j)
    return s - (U/A) - c

x = [-0.007,-0.01,-0.009,-0.004,0.005,0.011,0.018,0.027,0.037,0.048]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
c = 0.01
r = 0.01
R = 0.4
sold=0.
Aold=0.

for n,(U, t) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    j=n+1
    print("j={},U={},t={}".format(j,U,t))
    init = 0.01 # The starting estimate for the roots of f(s) = 0.
    roots = fsolve(f,init,args=(U, sold,R,t,r,Aold,j))
    s=roots[0]
    L=Lambda(s,sold,R,t)
    A=Annuity(L,r,Aold,j)
    print("s={},L={},A={}".format(s,L,A))
    print
    sold=s
    Aold=A
```

It gives following outputs :

```
j=1,U=-0.007,t=1
s=0.00289571337037,L=0.00482618895061,A=0.985320604999

j=2,U=-0.01,t=2
s=0.00485464221105,L=0.0113452406083,A=1.94349944361

j=3,U=-0.009,t=3
s=0.00685582655826,L=0.0180633847507,A=2.86243751076

j=4,U=-0.004,t=4
s=0.00892769166807,L=0.0251666093582,A=3.73027037175

j=5,U=0.005,t=5
s=0.0111024600844,L=0.0328696834011,A=4.53531159145

j=6,U=0.011,t=6
s=0.0120640333844,L=0.0280806661972,A=5.32937116379

j=7,U=0.018,t=7
s=0.0129604367831,L=0.0305170484121,A=6.08018387787

j=8,U=0.027,t=8
s=0.0139861021632,L=0.0351929301367,A=6.77353436882

j=9,U=0.037,t=9
s=0.0149883645118,L=0.0382416644539,A=7.41726068981

j=10,U=0.048,t=10
s=0.0159931206639,L=0.041597709395,A=8.00918297693
```

No idea if it's correct, but it looks likely to me. I guess you got the idea now and you will be able to make some adjustments.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I will look to see how better I can modify this, it's a big step! really appreciate your help

Comment: Its actually exactly what I am looking for, I had an excel file to compute the numbers but was looking to improve my python skills so wanted to code it too - the numbers match! Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer fits you, please mark it as accepted, so the question could be closed.